# Group and flatten a query into a variable number of fields

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've got three tables, one for workers, another one for folders and a third one that combines IDs from workers and folder indicating that the worker has access to the folder.
I need to fill a table representing whether the workers have access or not to the folders.
So far I've come up with this:

```
var accessQuery = from folder in db.FOLDERS
                  from worker in db.WORKERS
                  select new
                  {
                       Folder = folder.Name,
                       Worker = worker.Name,
                       Access = worker.FolderAccess.Count(f => f.ID_Folder == folder.ID_Folder) > 0
                  };
```

I'd use another query to get all the Folders and then create a DataTable where the first column would be the worker's name and then add each folder as a new column.

Then I'd iterate through each row to fill a DataTable with the access data. That DataTable I use to feed a GridView or to export the data.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to accomplish this with just one single query or at least a more efficient way as mine doesn't seem efficient at all.

Comment: I think that your query is almost finished, I would replace Count with Any function

Comment: Thanks for point that out!

Answer (score 1):

I ended coming with a solution. Not sure if it's the best (probably not) but it's better than what I was using. Thanks to Ako for point the 'Any' change as it seems better than the count.

Here's the whole code with the DataTable filling

```
//First I get a list of all the folders
var queryFolders = from f in db.FOLDERS
                   orderby f.Name
                   select new
                   {
                       f.Name
                   };

//Here there's the query I was looking for
var queryAccess = from f in db.FOLDERS
                  from u in db.USERS
                  orderby f.Name
                  select new
                  {
                      User = u.Name,
                      Access = u.FolderAccess.Any(x => x.ID_Folder == f.ID_Folder)
                  }
                  into crossJoin
                  group crossJoin by new { crossJoin.User } into results
                  select new
                  {
                      results.Key.User,
                      AccessList = results.Select(x => x.Access).ToArray()
                  };

//Now I wrap the queries into a DataTable so I can easily feed them to what I need
DataTable dtAccess = new DataTable();

dtAccess.Columns.Add("User");
foreach (var f in queryFolders)
{
    dtAccess.Columns.Add(f.Name, typeof(bool));
}

foreach (var a in queryAccess)
{
      DataRow userFolders = dtAccess.NewRow();
      userFolders["User"] = a.User;
      for (int i = 1; i <= a.AccessList.Length; i++)
      {
          userFolders[i] = a.AccessList[i - 1];
      }
      dtAccess.Rows.Add(userFolders);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join. FYI this is basic RDBMS sql query so imho you better learn sql query first before moving to linq2sql.

```
var accessQuery = from worker in db.WORKERS
                  join access in db.ACCESS on access.ID_Worker == worker.ID_Worker
                  join folder in db.FOLDERS on access.ID_Folder == folder.ID_Folder
                  select new
                  {
                       Folder = folder.Name,
                       Worker = worker.Name
                  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.
I'm guessing I have not explained myself as the output of that is nothing like what I'd need.
I'm looking for something like a flattened cross join where each record would contain the worker and a boolean representing the access availability for each folder (being those booleans all in the same order so I can use them to fill rows with a pattern)

Comment: Well, imho flattened cross join is inner join. And for the boolean, the resulted record from query above means that every user has access in mentioned folder.